# request and response in nodejs when you hit the URL

Tags: node.js

```
const http=require('http');
const fs=require('fs');

var server=http.createServer(getFromClient);
server.listen(3000);
console.log("server start");

function getFromClient(req,res){
    fs.readFile('./index.html','utf-8',(error,data)=>{
    console.log(data);
    console.log("-------------");
    var content=data.replace(/dummy_title/g,'Title will be here').replace('dummy_content','Content will be here');
    console.log(content);
    res.writeHead(200,{'Content-Type':'text/html'});
    res.write(content);
    res.end();
});
```

}

When I access localhost:3000,
console.log(data),console.log("-------------") and console.log(content) are displayed 4 times in console

Could someone explain why it happened?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That is normal - your browser makes more than one call.

Most browsers make a call to grab /favicon.ico for example.

Try to log the url:

```
console.log(req.url);
```

and you'll see what's being called.
Solution to this issue can be checking for request URL if it's fetching favicon.ico or not. Just add *req.url != '/favicon.ico'*  to your code

```
function getFromClient(req,res){
    if (req.url != '/favicon.ico') {
        fs.readFile('./index.html','utf-8',(error,data)=>{
            console.log(data);
            console.log("-------------");
            var content=data.replace(/dummy_title/g,'Title will be here').replace('dummy_content','Content will be here');
            console.log(content);
            res.writeHead(200,{'Content-Type':'text/html'});
            res.write(content);
            res.end();
        });
    }
}
```